# Firebase: Trigger event in Firestore on new user created in FirebaseAuth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I wrote a very simple Cloud Function to add some fields in Firestore with some info from the newly created FirebaseUser in FirebaseAuth.

In Firestore, I have a collection named "highscore". Everytime, a new user is created, I want to add a document with the firebaseusers uid as document, and 2 fields, like:

highscore/uid/score & highscore/uid/usernick (e.g highscore/fgt38gudg9/430 & highscore/fgt38gudg9/cooldude45)

This is my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.database()

//On user creation, trigger: Add information to /highscore/uid
exports.onUserCreation = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    const collection = db.collection("highscore")
    const userid = user.uid
    const usernick = user.displayName
    collection.doc(userid).set({
        score: 0
        user: usernick
    })

})
```

However, when the function is triggered, I run into this error:

```
TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at exports.onUserCreation.functions.auth.user.onCreate (/srv/index.js:11:24)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:120:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I can't figure this out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using Firstore:

```
const db = admin.firestore()
```

Answer (score 2):

[`admin.database()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App.html#database) gets you a reference to the Realtime Database instance for your project.  What you want to use instead is [`admin.firestore()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App.html#database).

Also, you will want to return the promise that you get from `set()`, otherwise, the operation might not complete before the function terminates.

```
return collection.doc(userid).set({
    score: 0
    user: usernick
})
```

Be sure to [read the documentation about terminating functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) to understand your obligations in dealing with async work represented by promises.